# Angular 5 routes

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, angular4

Подскажите мне пожалуйста, как мне правильно организовать нечто подобное:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PageComponent },
    { path: ':slug', component: PageComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
];
```

то есть: дефолтная страница - *PageComponent*, если есть slug опять же *PageComponent*, а если есть объявленый роут, такой как login, то уже *LoginComponent*

Comment: Немного не понял, а что сейчас не работает?

Comment: @Zicrael сейчас если обратится на url **/login**, то запрос уходит к PageComponent

Comment: Такого быть не может, значит ошибка где - то, мне нужен код, или хотя бы ошибка которая вылетает

Comment: @Zicrael не понимаю, зачем вам это, но вот, накидал новое приложение, вставил роуты, https://github.com/StereoFlo/angular-test

Comment: Зачем из роутера модуль сделал?  Посмотри как это сделано тут: https://github.com/Zicrael/product-catalog-angular-v5-/blob/master/src/app/app.routing.ts

Comment: @Zicrael вы пользуетесь вообще angular-cli? Попробуйте, быстрее чем писать руками =)

Comment: Это шутка такая?:) видимо ты даже репо не глянул, иначе бы сразу понял что там лишь роуты прописаны руками:)

Comment: @Zicrael я поправил, на гитхабе, сделал по-вашему. В итоге - все тоже самое, смысл - доказать, что нет смысла как делать роуты, модулем или иначе. Сам роутер работает одинаково, изменяются только входящие данные.

Comment: Тогда почему у вас он не работает, а у меня работает?

Comment: @Zicrael именно поэтому я написал первое сообщение

Comment: Консоль ничего не выдаёт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно поставить путь логина перед путем с параметром, тк иначе совпадение роута будет именно с параметром а не нужным роутом

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PageComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: ':slug', component: PageComponent },
];
```